# NoMethodError : undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass when trying to set link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, routes

I am facing the following issue:

I have a model "restaurant" and I want to make an "Edit Restaurant" link in the navbar. I tried inserting this li in my navbar:

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit Listing", edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant.id) %></li>
```

but by doing so I get this error on the exact same line:

```
NoMethodError : undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

I guess the :id is not passed out right

Here are my other corresponding files:

restaurant_controler.rb

```
      class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:search, :index, :show]
    before_action :check_user, except: [:search, :index, :show]


    def search
      if params[:search].present?
         @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:search])
      else
         @restaurants = Restaurant.all
      end
    end

    # GET /restaurants
    # GET /restaurants.json
    def index
      @restaurants = Restaurant.all
    end

    # GET /restaurants/1
    # GET /restaurants/1.json
    def show
      @reviews = Review.where(restaurant_id: @restaurant.id).order("created_at DESC")
      if @reviews.blank?
         @avg_rating = 0
      else
         @avg_rating = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
      end
    end

    # GET /restaurants/new
    def new
      @restaurant = Restaurant.new
    end

    # GET /restaurants/1/edit
    def edit
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /restaurants
    # POST /restaurants.json
    def create
      @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @restaurant.save
          format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @restaurant }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1
    # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'edit' }
          format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /restaurants/1
    # DELETE /restaurants/1.json
    def destroy
      @restaurant.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_restaurant
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
      end

      def check_user
        unless current_user.admin?
          redirect_to root_url, 
          alert: "Sorry, only admins can do that!"
        end
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def restaurant_params
        params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :adress, :phone, :website, :image, :description)
      end
  end
```

navbar:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <%= link_to "ListingsDemo", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><%= link_to "About", pages_about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Contact", pages_contact_path %></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
        <%= form_tag search_restaurants_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
              <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
              <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
          <% end %>
          </p>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "Edit Listing", edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant.id) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          <% else %>
             <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
             <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

routes.rb

```
      Yelpdemo::Application.routes.draw do


    resources :messages

    devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

    devise_for :users
    resources :restauarants do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
      resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
    end


    get "pages/about"
    get 'pages/contact', to: redirect('/messages/new')
    root 'restaurants#index'

  end
```

Restaurans/index.html.erb

```
  <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Adress</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
           <th colspan="2"></th>
        <% end %>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to restaurant.name, restaurant %></td>
          <td><%= restaurant.adress %></td>
          <td><%= restaurant.phone %></td>
          <td><%= link_to restaurant.website, restaurant.website %></td>
          <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_restaurant_path(restaurant), class: 'btn btn-link' %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', restaurant, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-link' %></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>

    <%= link_to 'New Restaurant', new_restaurant_path, class: 'btn btn-link' %>

  <% end %>

  <%= image_tag "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/listingsdemo/happy_footer.png" %>
```

Comment: Are there any `records` under the `restaurants table`? If there are no records then `@restaurant` will be `nil`.So `@restuarant.id` obviously gives you that error.

Comment: You should either set ```@restaurant``` object for all actions or show this link only if action is ```show```. I also recommend you to check user in destroy action.

Comment: Yes there are records in the restaurant table, all have the apropriate id!

Answer (score 1):

**Restaurant**

The problem you have isn't that the `id` method isn't being passed - it's that your `@restaurant` object has not been declared.

When I was looking through your code, I noticed you mentioned the error was in your *navbar*. This raised concerns for me, as the *navbar* element of your view suggests that it persists for more than one view

If this is the case, you need to make sure you have the `@restaurant` variable declared for *every* action:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_restaurant

   private

   def set_restaurant
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find 1 #-> you need to identify the restaurant
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You always get this error on `index` and `search` action. Because You are getting list of restaurant object in this methods not a single object of restaurant. You will get `@restaurant` nil in case of index action. You have to remove this action/link from navbar in case of index and search action. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

What view / route are you in and clicking on the navbar link? There is not information, but it seems like your @restaurant variable is nil so you actually haven't passed anything from the controller to the view.

The other thing is--generally speaking you can just refer to the path in erb as

`edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant)`

(no need for the '.id')

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I still get an error: ActionController::UrlGenerationError No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Just to clarify (per my above question), what controller method / view are you actually in when you get this error? It seems that @restaurant is nil, which is the main problem.

Comment: My navbar is set up as a partial so the link would appear on every page! I added the index page for the restaurant in my post above. There you can see that I have a line for editing the restaurant and it works to! Only when I try to move the link in the navbar I get the error!

Comment: Take a step back for a second--this is not a technical issue but a logic issue. Your `edit_restaurant_path` in restaurants/index.html.erb  is nested inside of an each loop, so you can refer to single restaurants ('restaurant' variable). Now when you put the same link in your navbar--how is the program supposed to know which restaurant you are referring to? This variable is undefined. Unfortunately our browsers cannot read our minds...it makes sense to wrap this navbar link in a conditional so it shows only for a 'show' view but zero sense in an 'index' view. Think about the logic.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback! I am not sure how to do what you suggested as I am kind of a newby in rails..I tried this ang got a little bit further: <li><%= link_to "Something", { controller: "restaurants", action: "edit", id: "@restaurant" } %></li>  . But the ID still doesnt get passed